# Getting maximum call stack size error in SAPUI5 application

Tags: ajax, sapui5

Getting maximum call stack size error on calling ajax post on login. Cant figure out exactly what is causing this issue. I cant seem to find any recursive function.

> Here is my xmlview file

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="abc.controller.LoginController"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"
    xmlns:c="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:m="sap.m"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt">
    <m:Page
        id="loginPage"
        showHeader="false"
        enableScrolling="false"
        class="sapUiContentPadding">
        <m:Panel width="30%">
            <l:Grid>
                <l:content>
                    <l:VerticalLayout>
                        <m:Label text="User Name" design="Bold"/>
                        <m:Input id="username"/>
                    </l:VerticalLayout>
                    <l:VerticalLayout>
                        <m:Label text="Password" design="Bold"/>
                        <m:Input id="password" type="Password" />
                    </l:VerticalLayout>
                    <l:VerticalLayout>
                        <m:Button id="loginBtn" text="Login" press="toTablePage" />
                    </l:VerticalLayout>
            </l:content>
            </l:Grid>
        </m:Panel>
        </m:Page>
</mvc:View>
```

> My login controller js file is

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/m/MessageToast"
], function(Controller, JSONModel, MessageToast) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("abc.controller.LoginController", {

        onInit: function(){

        },

        toTablePage: function(){

            var userName = this.byId("username");
            var password = this.byId("password");

            if(userName.getValue()!== "" && password.getValue()!== ""){



                    var aData = jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        url: "http://localhost:3000/api/logins",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: jQuery.param({ email: userName, password : password}) ,
                        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }

                    });
            }
            else
                MessageToast.show("the username or password is wrong");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `userName` and `password`, objects that have circular structures, to `jQuery.param`. You need to pass the actual `userName.getValue()` and `password.getValue()`.

`jQuery.param` is trying to serialize recursive objects. Which is a process that will never end.

Comment: Thanks @juan, Can you explain how `userName` and `password` is recursive objects ?

Comment: @user557657 It means that it has references to itself. I don't know exactly *where* the recursion is, but imagine the following (you can actually try it out in the devTools):

    `var a = {};
    a.self = a;`

if you want to write the resulting object as a string, you will notice that it is a never ending process: `{self: {self: {self: {self: ...}}}`